# Webpack resolve index.whatever.jsx automatically

Tags: reactjs, module, webpack, components, jsx

When using webpack to resolve my imports:

```
/component/thing/index.jsx
/component/stuff/index.jsx
```

can be imported like

```
import Thing from './component/thing';
import Stuff from './component/stuff';
```

because index.jsx is resolved automatically. Trouble is now I've got a large number of files named index.jsx in my project making searching for file difficult and annoying. Is there a way to configure webpack to accept something like:

```
/component/thing/thing.index.jsx
/component/stuff/stuff.index.jsx
```

but still allow shorthand imports like above?

---

My first instinct was to (in Webpack):

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.index.jsx']
}
```

but that didn't resolve. Is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [resolver plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin) might help you.

I haven't tried it. But according to the description, you should be able to do something like this.

```
resolve: {
  plugins: [
    new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin({
      transformFn: function(dirName) {
        // use this function to provide custom transforms of resolving directory name 
        // return desired filename or array of filenames which will be used 
        // one by one (honoring order) in attempts to resolve module 
        return [dirName + ".index", dirName + "/" + dirName + ".index"]
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how this `transformFn` works and that's why I return two possible paths as an array. Do some experiment with it and you will be able to find the correct path to return in your case.

Also, ensure that you that you are using the [correct version](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin/releases) of the plugin based on your webpack version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the folder/index.js structure? You could just have `thing.js` live in the `/component` folder so then you could use webpack resolve to import things in shorthand like you have above:

```
import Thing from 'component/thing';
import Stuff from 'component/stuff';
```

The webpack resolve would look something like this:

```
resolve: { 
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'], 
    extensions: ['.js'] 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep my components separated out into their own folders to keep the structure clean.